# Deep Learning Image for Google Compute Engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, gpu, google-compute-engine, amazon-ami

The **deep learning AMIs for AWS** make it easy to setup deep learning models (in particular, for using GPU instances), see:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/machine-learning/amis/.

For Google Compute Engine many blog posts/tutorials show how to set up a instance for deep learning by installing all required libaries manually ([Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20compute%20engine%20deep%20learning)). However, this provides not the same convenience that the "one-click-solution" of an AMI offers.

I am curious if there is a functionality like Amazon's AMIs for **Google Compute Engine** (in particular, some which makes setting up a deep learning instances with GPU instances a breeze)?

Comment: [This Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+compute+engine+deep+learning) brought up some promising results.  Can you tell us what you've researched so far, so that we don't have to play 20 questions?

Comment: Fair point. I am aware of those links and did the same Google search. I am rather searching for a one-click solution for GCE (in the same AWS offers it). BTW, I tried some of the tutorials, but failed (but that's a different story).

Comment: Can you structure your question in a way that it's not a product recommendation or search request?  Such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Sure. Tried to re-phrase the question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried [GPU enabled machine for deep learning](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/using-gpus) on Google cloud? This includes GPU-enabled machines that come with pre-installed tensorflow. You may want to try cloud ML engine as described in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/getting-started-training-prediction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCE now has the deep learning images.

- [Blog post](https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/deep-learning-images-for-google-cloud-engine-the-definitive-guide-bc74f5fb02bc)
- [Official docs](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm-image/)